# jquery datepicker in AngularJS still shows required after date is selected

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using a JQuery Datepicker in an AngularJS application.   When the datepicker is repopulated after a Web API GET request the field still shows as required.  I have tried various work-arounds but none have panned out so far.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks . . . Pete

Here is my datepicker code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <span class="input-group" ng-if="mode.indexOf('edit')==0">
        <input name="{{temp2.Field.Name}}"
            id="completionDate"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            datepicker-popup="M/d/yyyy"
            ng-model="item.Finish"
            is-open="openedDatePicker.Finish.open"
            min-date="openedDatePicker.Finish.minDate"
            max-date="openedDatePicker.Finish.maxDate"
            datepicker-options="dateOptions"
            close-text="Close"
            ng-required="item.Finish === null" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-
                click="openDatePicker($event,'Finish')"><i class="glyphicon 
                glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
             </span>
          </span>
          <p class="form-control-static" ng-if="mode.indexOf('edit')!=0">
          {{item.Finish | date:'M/d/yy (EEE)'}}</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: console the `item.Finish` after you pick a date, and make sure the `ng-model` is set.